# what to do when the java.lang.illegalSateException (Module entity with name: .... should be available) occurs?

Tags: android, exception

Alright so, i got the code from a coworker and when i start it with android studio i get this exception.

[image]

I guess, it might be as simple a what it states, a module is missing. But i dont know which one and the code works perfectly fine on the computer of my coworker.

I googeled the question as well, and the only anser one user gave in the intellij forum gave was, to lower the gradle version.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I haven't gotten this error before but I did some research to help, can you try this:

1. Rename your project directory to *exactly* match the value of `rootProject.name` in your root `settings.gradle`
2. File > Invalidate Caches... > Invalidate and Restart

Source: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-317606/Changing-only-the-case-of-the-Gradle-root-project-name-causes-exception-while-importing-project-java.lang.IllegalStateException#focus=Comments-27-7257761.0-0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 6):

select the Android to project and just delete the.gadle and .idea files [image: .gadle and .idea files] after that restart and invalidate cache selecting all checkbox and restart the android studio . [image: restart the android studio .]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the rootproject .name in your settings.gradle file is the same as your project folder name

Answer (score 2):

- Open `settings.gradle`
- rename `rootProject.name = "project_dir_name"`
- Sync project with gradle files or invalidate cache and restart